# Dynamically import image assets in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in reactjs with all image imported as

```
import client01 from '../../assets/images/site/client-01.png';
import client02 from '../../assets/images/site/client-02.png';
import client03 from '../../assets/images/site/client-03.png';
import client04 from '../../assets/images/site/client-04.jpg';
import client05 from '../../assets/images/site/client-05.jpg';
import client06 from '../../assets/images/site/client-06.jpg';
```

and used in code as

```
<img src={client05} alt="client_5" />
```

My question is if I'm getting these values from an api, then how should I load the images.
for example,

```
{
  "web-data": {
    "Asset": {
      "client01": "../../assets/images/site/client-01.png",
      "client02": "../../assets/images/site/client-02.png",
      "client03": "../../assets/images/site/client-03.png",
      "client04": "../../assets/images/site/client-04.png",
      "client05": "../../assets/images/site/client-05.png"
    }
  }
}
```

and i got these values and stored it in a local state, How to import these images in my reactjs component?

Comment: You can pass in the source like ```web-data.asset.client05``` it will give the same output. As long as the field has a valid url it is ok. It doesn't matter it is variable or hard code string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `require` method instead `import`

---

```
    <img src={require(web-data.Assets.client05)} alt="client_5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch those when you load the component and save them in component state. 
Inbetween you can show a loader spinner to the user:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state= {
    imagesLoaded: false,
    images: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(APIURL)
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ images: data.images, imagesLoaded: true });
    }
}
```

Then refer to those images in your component for example:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.imagesLoaded){
    return <LoaderSpinner />
  }

  return (
    {
      for (img in this.state.images) {
        return <img src={img}/>
      } 
    }
  )
}
```

I tried to keep it generic. Hope I understood your question correct and this helps